# mexHttpBinding - Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, config, meta, endpoint

I know this has been asked many times, and answered many times, but, all the provided samples that **should** be working don't seem to want to work for me today.

When I try to start the host, I keep getting the following error:

"The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service TraceService.  Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract."

My service is being hosted in a managed windows service host as per Microsoft's example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

And here is my nice and simple config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Daff.Lae.Service.TraceService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="TraceService" contract="Contracts.Service.ITraceService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/TraceService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Of course, the problem becomes more interesting when there are no errors if I remove this line:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Any help would be very very very greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Be sure to specify a `behaviorConfiguration` in the `service` element of your configuration in order to allow either `httpGet` or `httpsGet`.

I see that you have already defined a serviceBehavior named `DefaultBehavior` - now all you need to do is add `behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior"` to the `service` element, so that line becomes:

```
<service name="Daff.Lae.Service.TraceService" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
```

If you don't explicitly specify a behavior for your service, both HTTP GETs and HTTPS GETs are disallowed by default, and your metadata will not be exposed.

Comment: @agAus - Yes, but you have not specified that your service is to use your default behavior. You need to add the 'behaviorConfiguration' attribute to the 'service' element in your config, as shown in my answer.

Comment: Edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: Thank you.  That has fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

As you're using WS-Http you are binding to an HTTPS protocol, so you need to use the correct MEX binding;

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

and change the baseaddress to a https one.

Or (the other way around) convert your wsHttp binding to a basicHttp binding and things will start working for you.

Comment: Ahh...I didn't realise wsHttpBinding meant it was https?

I'm tied up with a prod release today but would definitely like to try this and get back to you.  I have bookmarked my question so I can update the post accordingly.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
`<services>
  <service  name="MyService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Service1" >

</services>
 `

 where MyService is the application name , Service1 is the default implementation class for IService1
 `
 <protocolMapping>
  //Remove any http or https bindings provided  
</protocolMapping>   
 `
It should help when you use WCF Application Project
```